# How to fix Build Failed React Native app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, ignite-ui

I am trying to run react-native app but it shows below error
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/gtcsys1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-bqzwxygpsrihljeavlpvpwsbtwbx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-F230A7F5FF4BC8599FC7C89764478EBD.sh